# MAVEN : Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor [ERROR]

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-archetype

I'm using Maven 3.6.3, when i tried to create a sample project using archetype :

```
mvn archetype:generate
    -DarchetypeGroupId=fr.fastconnect.factory.tibco.bw.maven
    -DarchetypeArtifactId=archetype-bw-default-project
```

This command **normally** generates a sample TIBCO BW5 project
but I got this error :

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/2.5/maven-clean-plugin-2.5.pom
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:jar:2.5
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-install-plugin/2.4/maven-install-plugin-2.4.pom
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.4: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.4 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:jar:2.4
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/2.7/maven-deploy-plugin-2.7.pom
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:jar:2.7
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-site-plugin/3.3/maven-site-plugin-3.3.pom
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.3: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.3 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:jar:3.3
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/1.3/maven-antrun-plugin-1.3.pom
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.3: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.3 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:jar:1.3
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/2.2-beta-5/maven-assembly-plugin-2.2-beta-5.pom
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.2-beta-5: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.2-beta-5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:jar:2.2-beta-5
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/2.8/maven-dependency-plugin-2.8.pom
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.8: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.8 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:jar:2.8
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-release-plugin/2.5.3/maven-release-plugin-2.5.3.pom
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.5.3: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.5.3 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:jar:2.5.3
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/fr/fastconnect/factory/tibco/bw/maven/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/fr/fastconnect/factory/tibco/bw/codereview/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/fr/fastconnect/factory/tibco/bw/fcunit/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/maven-metadata.xml
[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata fr.fastconnect.factory.tibco.bw.maven/maven-metadata.xml from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Transfer failed for https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/fr/fastconnect/factory/tibco/bw/maven/maven-metadata.xml
[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata fr.fastconnect.factory.tibco.bw.codereview/maven-metadata.xml from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Transfer failed for https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/fr/fastconnect/factory/tibco/bw/codereview/maven-metadata.xml
[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata fr.fastconnect.factory.tibco.bw.fcunit/maven-metadata.xml from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Transfer failed for https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/fr/fastconnect/factory/tibco/bw/fcunit/maven-metadata.xml
[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-metadata.xml from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Transfer failed for https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-metadata.xml
[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata org.codehaus.mojo/maven-metadata.xml from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Transfer failed for https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/maven-metadata.xml
[WARNING] Failure to transfer fr.fastconnect.factory.tibco.bw.maven/maven-metadata.xml from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer metadata fr.fastconnect.factory.tibco.bw.maven/maven-metadata.xml from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Transfer failed for https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/fr/fastconnect/factory/tibco/bw/maven/maven-metadata.xml
[WARNING] Failure to transfer fr.fastconnect.factory.tibco.bw.codereview/maven-metadata.xml from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer metadata fr.fastconnect.factory.tibco.bw.codereview/maven-metadata.xml from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Transfer failed for https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/fr/fastconnect/factory/tibco/bw/codereview/maven-metadata.xml
[WARNING] Failure to transfer fr.fastconnect.factory.tibco.bw.fcunit/maven-metadata.xml from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer metadata fr.fastconnect.factory.tibco.bw.fcunit/maven-metadata.xml from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Transfer failed for https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/fr/fastconnect/factory/tibco/bw/fcunit/maven-metadata.xml
[WARNING] Failure to transfer org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-metadata.xml from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer metadata org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-metadata.xml from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Transfer failed for https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-metadata.xml
[WARNING] Failure to transfer org.codehaus.mojo/maven-metadata.xml from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer metadata org.codehaus.mojo/maven-metadata.xml from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Transfer failed for https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/maven-metadata.xml
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  2.600 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-06-03T13:08:10+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] No plugin found for prefix 'archetype' in the current project and in the plugin groups [fr.fastconnect.factory.tibco.bw.maven, fr.fastconnect.factory.tibco.bw.codereview, fr.fastconnect.factory.tibco.bw.fcunit, org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local (C:\Users\FastConnect\.m2\repository), central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/NoPluginFoundForPrefixException
```

When i was looking for solutions for this problem i found people talking about adding **proxy** settings to my `settings.xml` but I'm not using any proxy

I have access to the urls of maven central (ex. https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/2.5/maven-clean-plugin-2.5.pom) in my browser which does not use any proxy settings

If anyone can help !

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SOLVED]

Actually it seems like `maven 3.6.3` is **only** compatible with `Java 8+`

so... I updated my java version to 8th version and It worked !

Hope this would help you !